# Is there a way to make the regression intercept conditional in R? Significantly different from another coefficient?

Tags: r, linear-regression

Let's say I have 3 categories of firms:

-Swedish firms

-British firms

-Norwegian firms

I do a linear regression model(lm()-function) on the profitability of these three types by using a dummy variable for each type.

Is there a way to instead of getting an intercept value to have the profitability of British firms as the intercept and the Swedish and Norwegian firms as coefficients? I want to know the coefficients and the significance of the difference between the British firms and the other categories and so on if that makes sense.

Comment: `lm(DV ~ 0 + firm)` will remove the intercept and give coefficient for each level of your "firm" factor variable, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: If `firm` is a `factor` variable and British firms are the first (reference) level, then `lm(profitability ~ firm)` will use British firms as the intercept and give you coefficients for the others. You can explicitly set the reference level of a factor with `relevel()`.

Answer (score 0):

Because R (1) sets the order of factors alphabetically by default and (2) uses *treatment contrasts* with the first level of the factor as the baseline, that is exactly what you will get by default if you run

```r
lm(profitability ~ nationality + ..., data = your_data)
```

where `...` are other covariates you want to account for. (If you want to allow for interactions between `nationality` and other covariates, use `~ nationality*(cov1 + cov2 + ...)`.

When R lists the coefficients you'll see `(Intercept)` (predicted value for British firms when all other covariates are 0); `nationalityNorwegian` (difference between Norwegian and British firms); and `nationalitySwedish` (Swedish vs British).

This is all assuming that you haven't changed the  order of the level of the factors somewhere else in your workflow; e.g. if you see parameters `(Intercept)`, `nationalityBritish`, `nationalitySwedish`, that implies that somehow you ended up with Norwegian as the baseline level.

The `faux` package provides factors that give slightly nicer/more interpretable parameter values.